# How to fetch drug and its alternate drug from First Databank dabase based on insurance plan coverage

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

I am developing a drug prescription system using mysql and zend framework. And I am stuck in First databank, actually I have to fetch all those drug and their alternate drug records from First databank database based on insurance plan because insurance plan gives list of coverage drugs in USA. But the problem is their is no any table related to insurance in database, so how we can map it with drugs table ? I have imported database in my mysql. This is url for service provider http://www.fdbhealth.com/ but it's support are not helping me because it is not providing any solution. Guys if you have any alternate solution for this, kindly suggest me.

Thank You

Comment: I'm not going to download data from an unknown provider and I doubt anyone else will either. If you care to edit your question to include sample data and expected results I would be happy to look again.

Comment: hi @P.Salmon, Thank you for taking interest , am not force to download data and this is not needed to download database, just asking if have you worked on this in past on first databank or have any idea then you can suggest.